# Login with Jsoup Java

Tags: java, jsoup

How to login via jsoup?

```
  <table border="0" cellpadding="8px"> 
   <tbody>
    <tr> 
     <td align="left"> <span id="ctl00_bodyContent_LabelTurni1" style="font-size: 13pt;">Nome utente</span> </td> 
     <td align="left"> <input name="ctl00$bodyContent$txtUser" type="text" size="30" id="ctl00_bodyContent_txtUser"> </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
     <td align="left"> <span id="ctl00_bodyContent_LabelTurni2" style="font-size: 13pt;">Password</span> </td> 
     <td align="left"> <input name="ctl00$bodyContent$txtPassword" type="password" size="30" id="ctl00_bodyContent_txtPassword" onfocus="this.select();"> </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
     <td> </td> 
     <td align="center"> <input type="submit" name="ctl00$bodyContent$btnLogin" value="Conferma" onclick="ValidateConfirm(); return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$bodyContent$btnLogin&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_bodyContent_btnLogin"> <input type="submit" name="ctl00$bodyContent$btnEsci" value="Esci" onclick="window.close(); return false;" id="ctl00_bodyContent_btnEsci"> </td> 
    </tr> 
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
Document doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://turni.contacts.com/Default.aspx").data("ctl00_bodyContent_txtUser", "user").data("ctl00_bodyContent_txtPassword", "password").data("ctl00_bodyContent_btnLogin","Conferma")
//.cookies(res.cookies()).timeout(0).post();
```

Comment: See example of answer below. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34584302/jsoup-to-login-to-a-webite

Comment: The name has a $ sign, not as underscore. Shouldn't you be using that?

Comment: I used $, I see no other _

Comment: Well, that login button calls something called WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions, so you probably have to chase down what that does. Enjoy ;)

Comment: I do not know where to start !! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually login into a web site requires two steps -

1. You send a `GET` request to get the page, and you extract from there
   some values like session ID etc, and the cookies.
2. You send a `POST` request with the values from step 1, and your user name and password.

To know which values you need to send, use your browser in the developer mode (by pressing F12) and examine the traffic. Change the `user agent` string to match your browser, since some sites send different pages to different clients. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871801/problems-submitting-a-login-form-with-jsoup).

Comment: It's hard to tell without accessing the actual page. I've tried http://turni.contacts.com/Default.aspx but couldn't reach it. Is it the real address?

Comment: Try to add ALL the fields that are present at the POST request, even the empty ones - __LASTFOCUS, __EVENTTARGET...