# jsoup to login to a webite

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup

I am trying to use jsoup to get information after logging into "http://pawscas.usask.ca/cas-web/login". I've tried what's below and it doesn't seem to work, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
Connection.Response res = null;
    try {
        res = Jsoup.connect("http://pawscas.usask.ca/cas-web/login")
            .data("username", "user") 
            .data("password", "pass")
            //.data("It", "some data")
            //.data("execution", "some data")
            //.data("_eventId", "submit")
            .method(Method.POST)
            .execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     //System.out.println(res.cookies());

    //This will get you cookies
    Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();

    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://paws5.usask.ca/web/home-community#mycourses")
          .cookies(loginCookies)
          .get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

Comment: How does it not work? Are the cookies valid? Have you tried using those cookies in a standalone app like Postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this buddy, basically the problem seems to be that the data you provided along with your request was not sufficient enough, you need to include **ALL input fields**.

And two of the inputs are a randomly generated number which seems to be associated with your session (the one with the name `lt` and `execution`), so first you need to get them, then pass it along with your data.

```
Connection.Response initialResponse = null;
    try {
        // get "lt" and "execution" value
        initialResponse = = Jsoup.connect("http://pawscas.usask.ca/cas-web/login").method(Method.GET).execute();
        Document doc = initialResponse.parse();

        // get lt
        Element lt = doc.select("input[name=lt]").first();
        String ltVal = lt.attr("value");

        // get execution
        Element execution = doc.select("input[name=execution]").first();
        String executionVal = execution.attr("value");

        // get cookies
        Map<String, String> cookies = initialResponse.cookies();

        // now do the login
        res = Jsoup.connect("http://pawscas.usask.ca/cas-web/login")
            .data("username", "user") 
            .data("password", "pass")
            .data("lt", ltVal)
            .data("execution", executionVal)
            .data("_eventId", "submit")
            .cookies(cookies)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36")
            .method(Method.POST)
            .execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     //System.out.println(res.cookies());

    cookies.putAll(res.cookies());

    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://paws5.usask.ca/web/home-community#mycourses")
          .cookies(cookies)
          .get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

Comment: this isn't working, when i try to connect to the second url (https://paws5.usask.ca/web/home-community#mycourses) it just gets redirected to the login page.

Comment: Can you successfully login though? What is the resulting html of `res`?

Comment: no successful login, the resulting html of res, is just the source of login page (http://pawscas.usask.ca/cas-web/login)

Comment: Try setting userAgent as this: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"

Comment: please see my updated answer again, basically I added another line `.cookies(cookies)`

Comment: adding cookies to the res connection fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

There are hidden parameters in that form that the server may be checking. Without knowing more about your error code, or what the server is doing, it's hard to answer your question. You can try doing a get first, with jsoup, find the values of the hidden parameters and post them back to the server to see if that helps, but if it doesn't then I don't know what:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lt" value="LT-3939609-Kw1VcYGxuNLKyEukchGOiWiBCzx0Mh" />
<input type="hidden" name="execution" value="e1s1" />
<input type="hidden" name="_eventId" value="submit" />
```