# How can I login to a website (meta refresh) with Jsoup?

Tags: java, android, http, jsoup

I'm trying to login using this.

```
res = Jsoup.connect("http://www.registru.liceu.asm.md/elev/login.php?user=Vozian_Valentin")
                   .data("pass", "DyXnyU")
                   .data("class","Clasa11B")
                   .data("submit","log in")
                   .method(Method.POST)
                   .execute();
```

When I call `res.parse().outerHtml()` it shows something diferent from successfully logged page or incorrect logged page and if I change the password to incorrect it shows the incorrect logged page.

Comment: Read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34551819/login-with-jsoup-java/34554702#34554702

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you're logged in, the server returns an HTML page with a `Refresh` meta tag.
Since Jsoup is an HTML parser, it can't handle this kind of redirect automatically. It has to be told to do so.

Here is how to do it:

```
private static final String UA_STRING = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1";
private static final String REFRESH_URL = "refresh-url";
private String loginFormUrl = "http://www.registru.liceu.asm.md/elev/login.php?user=Vozian_Valentin";

// Go to login form page
Response res = Jsoup.connect(loginFormUrl) //
                    .userAgent(UA_STRING) //
                    .data("pass", "DyXnyU") //
                    .data("class","Clasa11B") //
                    .data("submit","log in") //
                    .method(Method.POST) //
                    .execute();

// Extract the Refresh meta tag from server response
Element meta = res.parse().select("meta[http-equiv=Refresh]").first();
if (meta==null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to locate Refresh meta tag...");
}

// Determine the refresh url from the meta tag
String content = meta.attr("content");
meta.attr(REFRESH_URL, content.replaceAll("(?i)^(\\d+;.+URL=)(.+)$", "$2"));

// Go to refresh url
Response res2 = Jsoup //
  .connect(meta.absUrl(REFRESH_URL)) //
  .userAgent(UA_STRING) // 
  .referrer(loginFormUrl) //
  .method(Method.GET) //
  .cookies(res.cookies()) //
  .execute();

// Get the successfully logged page
System.out.println(res2.parse().outerHtml());
```