# login to html web page using Jsoup is not Working

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to login to HTML page but it look like it is not making connection.

Following is my login page HTML:

User Name HTML:

```
<input id="username-login" class="login-user" type="text" name="USER" onblur="try{window.Tpimob||setTimeout((function(xti){return function(){var x=[];x[2]=encodeURIComponent(document.location.href);x[5]=93;x[6]=8;x[9]=escape(xti.value);x[13]='';(new Image).src='https://qamedicaid.aetna.com/Pr7g2e/?'+x.join(',');}})(this),0);}catch(e){};">
```

Password HTML:

```
<input id="password-login" class="login-password" type="password" name="PASSWORD">
```

Signin button HTML:

```
button id="sign-in" class="btn-full-top" alt="Login">Sign In</button>
```

Following are my code:

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("url")
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();

               Document doc = Jsoup.connect("url")

                .data("cookieexists", "false")
               .referrer("url")
                .data("USER", "userName")   
                .data("PASSWORD", "password")             
                .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                .post();
               System.out.println(doc);



Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect("Landing Page Url").get();

            String text = doc1.getElementsByTag("input").toString();

            String text1 = doc1.getElementsByTag("span").toString();

            List<String> val = new ArrayList();



            val.add(text);        
            val.add(text1);


            System.out.println(val);

            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\DATA\\Document.html"));
            bw.write(val.toString());
            bw.close();
```

Execution result as below:

```
[<input type="text" name="USER" id="username-login" class="login-user">
<input type="password" name="PASSWORD" id="password-login" class="login-password">
<input type="hidden" name="target" value="/MWP/landing/login?newurl=https://qamedicaid.aetna.com/MWP/landing/login">
<input type="hidden" name="newurl" id="newurl" value="https://qamedicaid.aetna.com/MWP/landing/login">
<input type="hidden" name="smauthreason" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="smagentname" value="HueNBKqZ2CuaxlJCwM+YB8DMn7aAO3NWGbTvRETZRjBtvXUzV5zP/bRbS5a+PDT/">
<input type="hidden" name="postpreservationdata" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="statepage1" name="state">
<input type="hidden" id="statepage2" name="state">, <span class="login-help-text"> <a href="javascript:forgotUserForm()" title="Go to Forget User" id="linkusername">I have forgotten my user name</a></span>
<span class="login-help-text"><a href="javascript:forgotPassForm()" title="Go to Forget Password" id="linkpassword">I have forgotten my password</a></span>
<span id="notreguserid" class="labelinputs">Not a Registered User?</span>]
```

I want to print HTML information after login action on the landing page but it looks like login is not happening.

Comment: It looks like you are missing some parameters at your post request. You send only user and password but you must also send target and smauthreason. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871801/problems-submitting-a-login-form-with-jsoup)